# i wrote two ajax functions in $( document ).ready(). method of my html page

Tags: html, ajax, web-services

when i am try to refresh my web page for more times my web service files are not loading and my ajax     functions are not at working. i try to find out the error but no error i am getting. the only error is my web service file are not loaded and my all ajax functions are not at executing.
here is the link http://testing.way2hotel.com try to reload home page for more times(10 or 15) and any one can please check the error an let me knoww what error it is.

here is the html page and the web service file are

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for listing
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class listing : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    dbcon con = new dbcon();
    drdb_DAL dtdal = new drdb_DAL();
    public listing () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public homelist[] load_borrower_list()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        string given_baloan_amount = "0";
        con.mycon();
        List<homelist> lt_brlist = new List<homelist>();
        query = "select Top 10 bloan.borrower_id, bloan.bor_purpose, bloan.bor_amount, bloan.interest, bloan.loan_duration from borrower_required_loan_details bloan, borrower_pdetails bpdetails where bpdetails.profile_agreed='1' and bloan.borrower_id = bpdetails.borrower_id";
        DataTable dt = dtdal.dt_return(query);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd_br = new SqlCommand("select balance_amount from given_loan_details where borrower_id='" + dr["borrower_id"].ToString() + "'", con.sql);
                SqlDataReader sdread = cmd_br.ExecuteReader();
                if (sdread.HasRows)
                {
                    if (sdread.Read())
                    {
                        given_baloan_amount = dr[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
                sdread.Close();

                homelist hlist = new homelist();
                hlist.brid = dr["borrower_id"].ToString();
                hlist.br_amount = dr["bor_amount"].ToString();
                hlist.br_purpose = dr["bor_purpose"].ToString();
                hlist.br_interest = dr["interest"].ToString();
                hlist.br_duration = dr["loan_duration"].ToString();
                if (given_baloan_amount == "0")
                {
                    hlist.loan_balancereq_amt = dr["bor_amount"].ToString(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    hlist.loan_balancereq_amt = given_baloan_amount;
                }
                hlist.lnbalance_per = (float.Parse(given_baloan_amount) / (float.Parse(dr["bor_amount"].ToString()) / 100)).ToString();

                hlist.error = "true";
                lt_brlist.Add(hlist);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            homelist hlist = new homelist();
            hlist.error = "false";
            lt_brlist.Add(hlist);
        }
        return lt_brlist.ToArray();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public homelist[] load_lender_list()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        float tran_amount = 0;
        con.mycon();
        List<homelist> lt_brlist = new List<homelist>();
        query = "select Top 10 lloan.lender_id, lloan.invest_amount, lloan.invest_interest from lender_investment_details lloan, lender_details lpdetails where lpdetails.profile_agreed='1' and lloan.lender_id = lpdetails.lender_id";
        DataTable dt = dtdal.dt_return(query);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd_br = new SqlCommand("select tran_amount from given_loan_details where lender_id='" + dr["lender_id"].ToString() + "'", con.sql);
                SqlDataReader sdread = cmd_br.ExecuteReader();
                if (sdread.HasRows)
                {
                    while (sdread.Read())
                    {
                        tran_amount += float.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
                sdread.Close();

                homelist hlist = new homelist();
                hlist.lenid = dr["lender_id"].ToString();
                hlist.len_amount = dr["invest_amount"].ToString();
                hlist.len_interest = dr["invest_interest"].ToString();
                hlist.error = "true";
                hlist.lnbalance_per = (tran_amount / (float.Parse(dr["invest_amount"].ToString()) / 100)).ToString();
                hlist.loan_balancereq_amt = (float.Parse(dr["invest_amount"].ToString()) - (tran_amount / (float.Parse(dr["invest_amount"].ToString()) / 100))).ToString();
                lt_brlist.Add(hlist);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            homelist hlist = new homelist();
            hlist.error = "false";
            lt_brlist.Add(hlist);
        }
        return lt_brlist.ToArray();
    }

    public class homelist
    {
        // Borrower
        public string bname { get; set; }
        public string brid { get; set; }
        public string br_amount { get; set; }
        public string br_interest { get; set; }
        public string br_month { get; set; }
        public string br_purpose { get; set; }
        public string br_duration { get; set; }
        
         public string br_profilestatus { get; set; }
        // Lender
        public string lenid { get; set; }
        public string len_name { get; set; }
        public string len_amount { get; set; }
        public string len_interest { get; set; }
        public string len_month { get; set; }
        public string len_purpose { get; set; }
        public string len_duration { get; set; }
        public string len_profilestatus { get; set; }
        public string loan_balancereq_amt { get; set; }
        public string lnbalance_per { get; set; }
        // Error
        public string error { get; set; }
        public string err_msg { get; set; }
        // End
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/bootstrap/css/styles.css" />-->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/e3ecaab1/css/yii.css" />-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>-->
<title>Easylend.in | Home </title>
<link href="" rel="shortcut icon" type="" />
<!-- Custom Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcarousel.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jcarousel.css" />-->

<style>
.container {
 width:1000px;
}
 #loader  {
                    position: fixed;
                    left: 0px;
                    top: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    z-index: 1001;
                    background: rgba(255, 253, 253, 0.8);
                 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- <div id="loader">
        <img src="images/loading.gif" style="top:40%; left:50%; position:absolute;" alt="Loading"/>
    </div>-->
<!-- Start Header -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"style="margin-left: 0px;"><a href="index.html"><h1 style="font-size: 46px;">EASYLEND.IN</h1> <!--<img src="images/hotelspondy.png" alt="easylend.in" />-->
      <h2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;line-height:0px;margin-bottom:0;color:#000;"> Get a loan quickly </h2>
      </a></div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="top-right">
     
     
      <div class="main-menu navigation pull-left">
        <ul class="nav menu nav-pills">
         <li class="deeper parent "> <a href="index.html">HOME &nbsp;|</a>
           <li class="deeper parent "> <a href="lender.html">LENDERS &nbsp;|</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
              <li class=""> <a href="lender/how-to-lend.html">How to invest</a> </li>
              <li class=""> <a href="lender/know-your-borrower.html">Know your Borrower</a> </li>
              <li class=""> <a href="Listing/borrower-listings.html">Browse Borrower Listing</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="deeper parent "> <a href="borrowers.html">BORROWERS &nbsp;|</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
              <li class=""> <a href="borrower/how-to-borrow.html">How to get a loan</a> </li>
              <li class=""> <a href="borrower/creating-effective-borrower-listing.html">How to create effective listing</a> </li>
              <li class=""> <a href="Listing/lender-listings.html">Browse Lender Listing</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="deeper parent "> <a href="#">LISTINGS &nbsp;|</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
              <li class=""> <a href="Listing/borrower-listings.html">Borrower Listing </a> </li>
              <li class=""> <a href="Listing/lender-listings.html">Lender Listing </a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
         <!-- <li class="deeper parent "> <a href="group/group-lend.html">GROUP-LEND &nbsp;|</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
              <li class="item-142"> <a href="groups.html">Groups</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>-->
          <li class="deeper parent "><a href="about.html" >ABOUT US&nbsp;|</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
              <li class=""><a href="about/management.html" >Management</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="about/advisory-team.html" >Advisory Team</a></li>
              <!--<li class=""><a href="#" >Partners</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#">Media Room</a> </li>
              <li class=""><a href="#">Testimonials</a> </li>-->
              <li class=""><a href="careers.html">Careers</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="deeper parent" id="br_lender_signup"> <a href="#">SIGNUP &nbsp;|</a> 
               <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                  <li class=""><a href="Signup/borrower-signup.html" >Borrower</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="Signup/lender-signup.htm" >Lender</a></li>
               </ul> 
          </li>
         <li id="login_user" class="deeper parent"> <a href="login.htm">LOGIN</a> </li>
         <li id="user_name_display" class="deeper parent"> <a id="lgn_uname"> </a> 
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small"><li id="dashboard_link"></li><li id="user_br_logout"><a onclick="func_logout()"> Logout</a> </li> </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- End Header -->
<!-- breadcrumbs -->

<div style="height:15px"></div>

<div style="width:100%;min-width:1000px;">

  <div style="width: 60%;height: 220px;background-color:#2C3C59;float:left;">
  <div style="width:600px;margin: 20px 0px 0px 200px; padding:10px;">
      <p class="harabara black" style="font-size:40px"><span class="blue1" style="color:#E6BB10;">Lending. </span><span class="white" >Making. </span><span style="color:#68BB48;">Helping.</span></p>
      <br />
      <p class="lucidagrande" style="font-size:20px;text-align: center;color: white;"> Lend money to someone for a limited time.  </p>
      <!--<p class="lucidagrande grey" style="font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0;">Easylend.in is an online peer-to-peer lending platform in India connecting individual borrowers and individual investors. Register today for free and create your loan / investment account!</p>-->
    </div>
    <div style="width:500px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 178px;">
      <div style=" padding:20px 0 20px 30px">
        
        <div style="float:left;"><a style="margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold;width: 145px;background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E6BB10 0%,#E7D072 100%);border-bottom-color:#E7D072;" class="btn" href="#">LENDER</a>
        
        <div style="margin-top: 12px;padding-left:15px;"><h2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:17px;line-height:0px;margin-bottom:0;color:#fff;"> Safely invest money </h2></div></div> 
        <div style="float:right;"> <a style="margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold;width: 145px;border-bottom-color: #68BB48 !important;background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68BB48 0%,#90E072 100%);" class="btn" href="#">BORROWER</a>
        
        <div style="margin-top: 12px;padding-left:15px;"><h2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:17px;line-height:0px;margin-bottom:0;color:#fff;"> Get a loan quickly </h2></div></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        
     </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div style="width: 40%;height: 220px;background-color:#2C3C59;float:left;text-align: center;">
    <!--<img src="assets/img/hm1.png" />-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="container" style="padding:20px 0 0 0">
 <div class="ralewaymedium">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"> About Easylend </div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 450px;padding: 30px;"><p style="padding-top:10px;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0;text-align: justify; text-align: justify;letter-spacing: 0.5px;">"Easylend is one of the best ways to get the little extra money when we are in dire need. The people are very friendly and have helped me in every possible way. Thanks to the entire team for the great work. "</p>
    <p class="green" style="padding:0px;margin:0;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;" >- Sanjai.</p></div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 400px; padding: 30px 55px 30px 25px;"><p style="padding-top:10px;font-size:15px;line-height:17px;margin:0;text-align: justify;letter-spacing: 0.5px;">"Easylend is one of the best ways to get the little extra money when we are in dire need. The people are very friendly and have helped me in every possible way. Thanks to the entire team for the great work. "</p>
    <p class="green" style="padding:0px;margin:0;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;" >- Imran Hussian.</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div style="width: 470px; border-right:1px solid #EFEFEF;padding:5px 15px 5px 5px;float:left;">
   <!-- <div style="font-size:20px; padding:17px 0 17px 75px;background:url(images/circle-star.png) no-repeat;"> News & Updates </div>
    --> 
     <div style="padding:20px 30px 20px 30px">
        <div style="font-size:20px;border-bottom:solid 2px #CBCBCB;padding-bottom:10px;color: #68BB48;"><span style="float:left">Borrower Listings</span> <span style="float:right"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-user-toolbar/512/banker-24.png" /></a></span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="br_list_show"></div>

      <!--  <div style="font-size:13px;border-bottom:solid 2px #CBCBCB;padding:10px 0 10px 0;">
     
 
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- End body container -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- start footer -->
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container" style="padding:20px 0;">
    <div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li class="heading">About Easylend</li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <!-- <li><a href="how-easylend-work.htm">How it Works</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="about/management.html">Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="about/advisory-team.html">Advisory</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li class="heading">Investors</li>
        <!--<li><a href="lender/how-to-lend.html">Why Invest</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="lender/how-to-lend.html">How to Lend</a></li>
        <li><a href="Listing/borrower-listings.html">Browse Borrower Listings</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="#">How to read Borrower Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="group/group-lend.html">Group Lending</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="lender/lender-faq.html">Lender FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li class="heading">Borrowers</li>
        <!--<li><a href="#">Why Borrow</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="borrower/how-to-borrow.html">How to Borrow</a></li>
        <li><a href="Listing/lender-listings.html">Browse Lender Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="borrower/creating-effective-borrower-listing.html">How to create effective listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="borrower/borrower-faq.html">Borrower FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li class="heading">General</li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.htm">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="general-faq.htm">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="legal-agreements.html">Legal Agreements</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  <!-- End Footer Container --> 
</div>
<div class="copyright">
  <div class="container"><strong style="padding-left:25px;font-size:11px;">Copyright &copy; 2014 Natura Web Solutions</strong></div>
</div>
<!-- end footer -->
<!-- page -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/display_logout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // display if login
    var login_webservice = "webservice/login.asmx/ret_value";
    var br_db = "users/borrower/Dashboard.htm";
    var len_db = "users/lender/Dashboard.htm";

    var loginpage = "login.htm";
    var logout_webservice = "webservice/login.asmx/func_logout";

    login(login_webservice, br_db, len_db);
    // logout 
    function func_logout() {
        logout(logout_webservice, loginpage);
    }
    // End

//    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
//        $("#loader").show();
//    });
//    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
//        $("#loader").hide();
//    });

//    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
//    r.open("POST", "webservice", true);
//    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
//        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
//        console.log(r.responseText);
//    };

    // borrrower purpose in array if value come from database check index and display value
    var ar_purpose = new Array("Debt Consolidation", "Home Furnishing / Appliances", "Home Improvement", "Education", "Auto Purchase", "Wedding", "Travel / Vacation", "Family Event", "Medical", "Relocation Expenses", "Others");
    // End
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        first();
        second();
    });
//    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
//        if (jqxhr.readyState == 0 || jqxhr.status == 0) {
//            return; //Skip this error  
//        }
//    });

    function first() {
        
        var firstajaxcall = null;

//        if (firstajaxcall && firstajaxcall.readyState != 4 && firstajaxcall.readyState != 0) {
//            alert(firstajaxcall.readyState);
//            firstajaxcall.abort();
//        }
       firstajaxcall = $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "webservice/ws_home.asmx/load_lender_list",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
//            cache: false,
//            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
//                if (firstajaxcall != null) {
//                    firstajaxcall.abort();
//                }
//                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
//            },
            success: function (setvalue) {
                if (setvalue.d[0].error == "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < setvalue.d.length; i++) {
                        var len_append_value = '<div style="font-size:14px;border-bottom:solid 2px #CBCBCB;padding:10px 0 10px 0; font-weight:100"><div style="width:125px;height:32px; float:left;overflow:hidden;"><strong><a href="view/lender-view.htm?id=' + setvalue.d[i].lenid + '" class="investeridcls">' + setvalue.d[i].lenid + '</a></strong></div><div style="width:190px; float:left" ><div style="font-size:14px;float:left">willing to Invest</div><div style="float:left;width:80px;text-align:right;">&nbsp; ' + setvalue.d[i].len_amount + ' INR</div></div><div style="width:110px; float:left"> ' + setvalue.d[i].len_interest + ' %</div><div style="width:300px; float:left;font-size:13px">Higher Returns</div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
                        $("#lender_list_show").append(len_append_value);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    //alert(setvalue.d[0].err_msg);
                    $("#lender_list_show").append('<div style="padding:10px;">Please <a href="Signup/lender-signup.htm">click here</a> to Sign-up and be the first.</div>');
                }
            },
            failure: function () {
                //alert("failure");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                 alert("error" + response.d);
            }
        });
    }

    function second() {
        var secondajaxcall = null;
//        if (secondajaxcall && secondajaxcall.readyState != 4 && secondajaxcall.readyState != 0) {
//            secondajaxcall.abort();
//        }
        secondajaxcall = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "webservice/ws_home.asmx/load_borrower_list",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
//            cache: false,
//            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
//                if (secondajaxcall != null) { secondajaxcall.abort(); }
//                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
//            },
            success: function (setvalue) {
              
                if (setvalue.d[0].error == "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < setvalue.d.length; i++) {
                        var borrower_purpose = ar_purpose[setvalue.d[i].br_purpose];
                        var br_append_value = '<div style="font-size:14px;border-bottom:solid 2px #CBCBCB;padding:10px 0 10px 0;"><div style="width:125px; height:32px;float:left;overflow:hidden;"><strong><a href="view/borrower-view.htm?brid=' + setvalue.d[i].brid + '" class="Borroweridcls">' + setvalue.d[i].brid + '</a></strong></div><div style="width:130px; float:left"><div style="font-size:14px;width:35px;float:left">wants</div> <div style="width:65px;float:left;text-align:right">' + setvalue.d[i].br_amount + '</div></div><div style="width:160px; float:left"> ' + setvalue.d[i].br_interest + ' % &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:12px">for</span> <div style="float:right"> ' + setvalue.d[i].br_duration + ' Months</div></div><div style="width:300px; float:left; font-size:13px;">' + borrower_purpose + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
                        $("#br_list_show").append(br_append_value);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //alert(setvalue.d[0].err_msg);
                    $("#br_list_show").append('<div style="padding:10px;">Please <a href="Signup/borrower-signup.html">click here</a> to Sign-up and be the first.</div>');
                }
            },
            failure: function () {
                // alert("failure");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                 alert("error" + response.d);
            }
        });
    }

</script>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: TL;DR - You likely want to run them one at a time. So run next one in the success of the previous one. Alternatively run ONE and return all the values you get now one by one

Comment: @mplungjan sorry i didn't get you can you explain by using above coding

Comment: I seems to me you are running all the Ajax code immediately - that may give some issues with concurrency. Since you are calling your webservices for very little data you might want to get them all in one go

Comment: thank u @mplungjan, is there any solutions for that concurrency issues with out modifying weservice file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function processBriefRequest(setValue) {
  if (setvalue.d[0].br_error == "true") { // why not "false" here?
    $("#b_dashboarddetails").append('<tr><center><td>Status</td><td>-</td><td> ' + setvalue.d[0].br_profilestatus + '</td></center></tr><tr><center><td>Loan Amount</td><td>-</td><td>' + setvalue.d[0].bramount + ' INR </td></center></tr>');
    return; 
  }   
  alert(setvalue.d[0].error_msg);
}
function processLoanRequest(setValue) {
  if (setvalue.d[0].br_error == "true") { 
    $("#b_dashboarddetails").append('<tr><center><td>Loan Request</td><td>-</td><td>' + setvalue.d.length + '</td></center></tr>');
    return; 
  }   
  alert(setvalue.d[0].error_msg);
}  
function processActiveLoan(setValue) {
  if (setvalue.d[0].br_error == "true") {
    $("#b_dashboarddetails").append('<tr><center><td>Active loans</td><td>-</td><td>' + setvalue.d.length + '</td></center></tr>');
  }
  else if (setvalue.d[0].br_error == "false") {
    $("#b_dashboarddetails").append('<tr><center><td>Active loans</td><td>-</td><td>0</td></center></tr>');
  }
}
var processes = [
  { url: "../../webservice/ws_borrower.asmx/dashboard_broower_briefdetails",callback:processBriefRequest },
  { url: "../../webservice/ws_borrower.asmx/dashboard_broower_loanrequest",callback:processLoanRequest }
  { url: "../../webservice/ws_borrower.asmx/dashboard_broower_activeloans",callback:processActiveLoan}
], cnt=0;  

function callService() {
  if (cnt>=processes.length) return;
  var process = processes[cnt];
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url=process.url,
      data: "{}",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (setvalue) {
        process.callback(setValue);
        cnt++
        callService();
      },
      failure: function () {
         // alert("failure");
      },
      error: function (response) {
          alert("error" + response.d);
      }
  });


  $(function() {
    callService()
  });
```

Comment: thank u for your reply i tried this code but i am not getting any thing, ajax functions not calling web service files.